# jQuery variable selector Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io

I want to prepend html code into the DOM after receiving a nodejs message...

```
socket.on('new-message', function(message) {
    $(message).prependTo('#messages').hide().slideDown();
});
```

I get this error message:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:

```
<li class="timeline-message">
    <div class="well">
        <div class="timeline-header">
            <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8eb1b522f60d11fa897de1dc6351b7e8?s=50&amp;d=wavatar" alt="John" class="shadow" />
            <h4>
                New message from John<br/>
            </h4>
            <small>March 20th at 12:19am</small>
        </div>
        oo
    </div>
</li>
```

If I enclose the variable into tags it works well:

```
$('<div>' + message + '</div>').prependTo('#messages').hide().slideDown();
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you show the actual contents of `message`? It seems jQuery can't parse it as HTML (what you expected) or a selector.

Comment: It looks like `message` is not a string, but object that can not be converted to valid HTML.

Comment: @inser: I believe, `'<div>' + message + '</div>'` wouldn't work then.

Comment: If you use the latest jQuery version, try `$($.parseHTML(message))`.

Comment: Try to use `$("#messages").prepend(...).hide().slideDown();` in stead. Both simpler to understand and might be easier for jquery to understand when the message variable is acting up.

Comment: @Cort3z: I did this solution and it works but the hide and slideDown is exectued on $('#messages') and not on the prepended HTML code.

Comment: @FelixKling: I am using the latest jQuery version and with your solution I get this error message : "Cannot set property 'cur' of undefined"

Comment: @pjehan: Right.. Do something like: `$("#messages").hide().prepend(..., function(){$(this).parent().slideDown();});`. Something like that. Sorry for being a bit diffuse. Hopefully it is somewhat helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your help... I finally made it this way:
$('#messages').prepend(message).find('li:first-child').hide().slideDown();

I don't think it's the best way though...